# Capture element shows 90 degree preview in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have following code for capture element in my xaml.

```
  <CaptureElement Width="400" Height="400" x:Name="cameraCapture" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,0,0,40">
  </CaptureElement>
```

My page loaded

```
   private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        await captureManager.InitializeAsync();
        cameraCapture.Source = captureManager;
        await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
```

in preview it shows rotated image
[image]

if I set rotation to preview than in view it works fine but saved image is still rotated to 90 degree. How can I fix this?

```
   captureManager.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
```

Answer (score 1):

After you call `CapturePhotoToStreamAsync` you should apply these things on the stream:

```
 //create decoder and encoder
 BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
 BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(imageStream, dec);

 //roate the image
 enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;

 //write changes to the image stream
 await enc.FlushAsync();
```

It's just a snippet, but I guess you get the idea.
For full code sample take a look here: https://dzone.com/articles/how-capture-photo-your-windows-0